# How can I create an OpenTelemetry backend?

Tags: open-telemetry

I am aware that there are open source backends like Jaeger, Zipkin etc and commercial vendors like DataDog, New Relic etc.

I wanted to know if there is any specifications we need to follow when creating a custom backend or if there is guide to on how to do it.

I know that i can host a server and send telemetry to the server's URL. When i do this via a Collector it is in `proto` format and if done via Exporter it is in `json` format. Are there any other such points to consider?

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to know if there is any specifications we need to follow when creating a custom backend or if there is guide to on how to do it.

There is nothing like that. It's not within the scope of the OpenTelemetry project (at least for now). You are free to implement it in whatever way makes sense to you.

> When i do this via a Collector it is in proto format and if done via Exporter it is in json format

This is not entirely correct. There are various options for protocol + encoding. There are both OTLP Proto over HTTP/gRPC and HTTP/JSON exporters.

Comment: You are right the protocol and encoding can be configured.